# Event booking form for wordpress

Tags: events, plugin-events-calendar

Cannot find plugin which will allow me to [do this](http://img.flashtux.org/img13303021ff7fx7338823b.png):

I want to accept event bookings on my website like on the screenshot.
Below text fields event list will be presented and green will show events with available seats, red will show sold out. I want to set event list and free/sold out status in admin panel manually.

All my events are 3-days each so manual period selection using jquery calendar is not for me. I want just event list.

Also I want this plugin to let me track all the bookings in admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

That's quite a specific criteria- there are numerous event management plug-ins out there with bookings built in, but none will provide exactly what you are after. In general they will all have some form of date-picker (usually jQuery datepicker) - that's because in general people will want to manually select dates.

My suggestion is to create your own plug-in :D. Or adapt (extend) an existing one. The following plug-ins provide booking registration. In general though, they'll provide more than you need and not quite the UI you are after - but plug-ins are designed to cater for wide audiences, if you want something more bespoke you'll have to build it yourself, or pay someone to do it for you.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-made-easy/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-registration/

My own plugin [Event Organiser](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/), does not provide booking automatically. But [this 'add-on'](http://pastebin.com/xkH3mCVb) does provide an extremely basic interface which you could build on.